# Mapping streams by language in FFmpeg output reversed

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, converters, ffprobe

I'm using the command obtained in this topic to convert multiple videos by removing the audio track, however the output is always reversed the audio and video stream.

The output of audio and video is reversed how to correct in this same command would have how?

```
 ffmpeg -i "in.mkv" -map 0:a -map -0:m:language:eng -map 0:v -map 0:s -map 0:d? -map 0:t -c:v copy-c:a:0 aac -b:a:0 192k -ac 2 -ar 48000 -strict -2 "out.mkv"
```

Comment: Let `-map 0:v` be the very first map.

Comment: How? I could give you an example.

Comment: Place it before all other `-map`s

Comment: the video track with flag "eng" are removed too, I would like it to be just the audio. What can I do?